# How do I switch focus groups (via keyboard) immediately?

Tags: flutter, web, desktop

When traversing from one focus group to the next (with tab on keyboard) I expect the focus to move to the first field in the next group, but it seems to focus on nothing - and then another tab moves into that group.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                FocusableActionDetector(
                  onFocusChange: (focused) {
                    if (!focused) {
                      print('Have left focus group');
                    }
                  },
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 150,
                          child: TextField(),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Dartpad example](https://dartpad.dev/510e3c43a0368324c09dc8d96f802346?null_safety=true)

I expect that after the last field in the first group a press of `Tab` should move focus immediately to the first item in the next focus group.

I have tried all manner of `FocusNode`, `FocusScope`, `FocusScope.of(context).___`, however I am finding the focus management in Flutter a bit confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Preface: I'm not an expert on `Focus` and find it quite convoluted myself.

But the below works for what you're after, I believe, **traversing from one column to the next, without focusing "invisible" items**.  At least on mobile devices.  Web platform... that's a whole different ballgame (and I doubt it works the same).

I got rid of the `FocusableActionDetector` (which acts as a `FocusNode` itself) and wrapped each Column in a `FocusTraversalGroup`.  I believe Flutter tries to go from TraversalGroup to TraversalGroup when it can.

The `FocusScope` wrapping the TraversalGroups prevents the Back button and any other clickable items from getting focus (once the `FocusScope` has gained focus).

```
class MyHomePage2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FocusScope( // LIMIT FOCUS TO DESCENDANTS
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                  FocusTraversalGroup( // CREATE GROUPS HERE
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 150,
                            child: TextField(),
                          ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Summary

(to the best of my knowledge, which is fuzzy)

- `FocusScope` limits node traversal to its direct descendant nodes

  - focus will not traverse from one `FocusScope` to another `FocusScope`
  - to go to another `FocusScope` the user will need to either manually/click-focus the other `FocusScope`, or its descendant nodes must `requestFocus`
  - using `FocusScope` instead of `FocusTraversalGroup` above, would limit node traversal to one `Column`, whichever got focus.  It would not jump from one `Column` to the next when reaching last `TextField`
- `FocusTraversalGroup` collects descendants into a group for traversal

  - but focus **will** leave this group for another group
  - jumps when at final child node and another `FocusTraversalGroup` is available
  - can adjust traversal order within its group

#### Debug

Dumping the focus tree using `debugDumpFocusTree` (a static function available everywhere) can be helpful in debugging.

I sometimes add it to the AppBar for easy, on-demand access:

```
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Focus Tab Page'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.info_outline), onPressed: debugDumpFocusTree)
        ],
      ),
```

I've copied to relevant part below.

```
└─Child 2: FocusScopeNode#c83f0(_ModalScopeState<dynamic> Focus Scope [IN FOCUS PATH])
  │ context: FocusScope
  │ IN FOCUS PATH
  │ focusedChildren: FocusScopeNode#7d536([IN FOCUS PATH])
  │
  ├─Child 1: FocusScopeNode#7d536([IN FOCUS PATH])
  │ │ context: FocusScope
  │ │ IN FOCUS PATH
  │ │ focusedChildren: FocusNode#1b886([PRIMARY FOCUS]),
  │ │   FocusNode#72c3b, FocusNode#34b25, FocusNode#3b410,
  │ │   FocusNode#02fac, FocusNode#61cd5
  │ │
  │ ├─Child 1: FocusNode#1d51e(FocusTraversalGroup)
  │ │ │ context: Focus
  │ │ │ NOT FOCUSABLE
  │ │ │
  │ │ ├─Child 1: FocusNode#3b410
  │ │ │   context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#70699]
  │ │ │
  │ │ ├─Child 2: FocusNode#34b25
  │ │ │   context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#7c822]
  │ │ │
  │ │ └─Child 3: FocusNode#72c3b
  │ │     context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#f00bc]
  │ │
  │ └─Child 2: FocusNode#bdb17(FocusTraversalGroup [IN FOCUS PATH])
  │   │ context: Focus
  │   │ NOT FOCUSABLE
  │   │ IN FOCUS PATH
  │   │
  │   ├─Child 1: FocusNode#1b886([PRIMARY FOCUS])
  │   │   context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#c5a56]
  │   │   PRIMARY FOCUS
  │   │
  │   ├─Child 2: FocusNode#61cd5
  │   │   context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#a4dd8]
  │   │
  │   └─Child 3: FocusNode#02fac
  │       context: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey<EditableTextState>#fe12d]
  │
  ├─Child 2: FocusNode#4886e
  │   context: Focus
  │
  └─Child 3: FocusNode#9241b
      context: Focus
```

Comment: Perfect answer, nice bonus about using `debugDumpFocusTree`!

`FocusTraversalGroup` was primarily what I needed, and you helped me understand how it works much better. In addition for my use case I need to set the selection of the `TextField` when focused, so I wrap the TextFields with a `Focus` with `skipTraversal: true` and set the controller selection inside `onFocusChange`.

Thank you for the excellent answer, much appreciated! <3